# draw specific shape with geoJson

Tags: javascript, jquery, geojson, shapefile, qgis

Iam attempting to draw a Architectural Buildings shape with geoJSON on the browser

the story is: i want to make shapefiles by ( udig or qgis ) and convert the shapefile to geoJSON and then make the shape on the browser by the shapefile.
i all ready can make shapefile and convert it to geoJSON

i have been searched everything but just find 3 library for geoJSON ( openlayer /Leaflet/ Mapbox ).
these are good and helpfull but the only this is that they all need to load world map,that i dont want to be load.
i can't configure these library to build my custom map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution with Leaflet library

here is the sample code

```
// a GeoJSON multipolygon
var mp = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [
          [
            [101.2, 1.2], [101.8, 1.2], [101.8, 1.8], [101.2, 1.8], [101.2, 1.2]
          ],
          [
            [101.2, 1.2], [101.3, 1.2], [101.3, 1.3], [101.2, 1.3], [101.2, 1.2]
          ],
          [
            [101.6, 1.4], [101.7, 1.4], [101.7, 1.5], [101.6, 1.5], [101.6, 1.4]
          ],
          [
            [101.5, 1.6], [101.6, 1.6], [101.6, 1.7], [101.5, 1.7], [101.5, 1.6]
          ]
        ],
        [
          [
            [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0]
          ],
          [
            [100.35, 0.35], [100.65, 0.35], [100.65, 0.65], [100.35, 0.65], [100.35, 0.35]
          ]
        ]
      ]
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "MultiPolygon",
    "style": {
        color: "black",
        opacity: 1,
        fillColor: "white",
        fillOpacity: 1
    }
  }
};

// create a map in the "map" div, set the view to a given place and zoom
var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [0.8, 100.9],
  zoom: 8
});
new L.GeoJSON(mp, {
  style: function(feature) {
      return feature.properties.style
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

and the html

```
<div id="map" style="height:480px; width:360px;"></div>
```

dont forget to load Leaflet require file